# Solving limit $ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{7+x^3}-\sqrt[2]{3+x^2}}{x-1}\right) $ without L'Hopital.

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

I was trying all the day to resolve this problem with different method without L'Hopital but I can't do it, I would really like to up my mathematical development but the post doesn't allow me because I have less than 10 of reputation to up a image, so [here is a link to one of me best try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/twDBF.jpg)

$$ \lim_{x\rightarrow 1}\left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{7+x^3}-\sqrt[2]{3+x^2}}{x-1}\right)
 $$

Comment: Why? $\qquad \qquad$

Comment: Regarding your try, it is false in general that $\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}=\sqrt{a+b}$.

Comment: it was a test that i did yesterday but i couldn t do that problem, so i am tring to solve now

Comment: The factorization $$(a^n-b^n)=(a-b)(a^{n-1}+a^{n-2}b+a^{n-3}b^2+\cdots+b^{n-1})$$ often helps in instances with roots. If the roots are the same, you can blindly use this. If the roots are different, you'd choose $n$ so that it is the least common multiple of the roots involved.

Comment: Hint:
$$\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\root3\of{7+x^3}-2}{x-1}-\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\sqrt{3+x^2}-2}{x-1}.$$ Then use $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(\cdots)$ and $a^2-b^2=(a-b)(\cdots)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Use the (rather lengthy, but perfectly working) identity $$a-b=\frac{a^6-b^6}{a^5+a^4b+a^3b^2+a^2b^3+ab^4+b^5}$$

Comment: with $$\displaystyle a=\sqrt[3]{7+x^3}
$$ and $$\displaystyle b=\sqrt[2]{3+x}
$$?

Comment: @mrpepo877 Yes, of course.

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{x\to1}\dfrac{(7+x^3)^{1/3}-2}{x-1}=\dfrac{d(7+y^3)^{1/3}}{dy}_{(\text{ at   }y=1)}=?$$